# Help Heisenberg Group Homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

$H_n = \left\{ [x,y,z]:=  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & x & z \\
0 & 1 & y \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right) | x,y,z \in \mathbb{Z_n} \right\} $ i.e. the finite Heisenberg group with relations
$$\langle x,y,z | \  z = xy x^{-1} y^{-1} , zx=xz, zy = yz \rangle$$
is a homomorphism from $H$ to $x^{a} y^{b} z^{c}$. I multiplied the matrix and keep getting $x^{a1+a2}$$y^{c1+c2}$$z^{b2+a1c2+b1}$ which won't equal what I need to have a homomorphism i.e. $x^{a1+a2}$$y^{c1+c2}$$z^{b2+b1}$...Basically I have that extra $z^{a1c2}$ in the way. The teacher told me I can get rid of it using the relations. I tried but I'm lost. He said whenever there is a p, we have a pz from relations. I used that but can't get $z^{a1c2}$ term out of it. Help?

Comment: You are taking the wrong approach!